How to select a datagrid row by clicking outside the content
Sorry in advance about my English, it's not my first language.
I'm just starting out in C# WPF and I'm currently developing an application to return data from a database.
I'm using datagrid for this. It works very well.
My datagrid:

But I have a problem when I want to click on a line. I can only select a line if I click on the contents of a cell. I've tried to correct this problem with other topics on stackoverflow or on the internet, but I haven't managed to fix it or I've misunderstood things or done things wrong.
To better understand my problem, I've added colors to the screenshot below. When I click in the red zone, it works. When I click in the black zone, it doesn't work.
My datagrid with colors:

I've tried removing padding, margin and setting vertical alignment to Stretch. It works, but the result is not what I want. The text is not in the center, stuck to the lines.
My datagrid with stretch:

Is it possible to select the line by clicking anywhere on it (red and black zone) ? Keeping the style I want, with padding, margin and vertical alignment at center.
Here's my code.
Datagrid :
<!--Data Grid-->
<DataGrid Grid.Row="3" Margin="30 40 20 20" ItemsSource="{Binding UsersCollectionView}" SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedUser, Mode=TwoWay}"
          RowStyle="{DynamicResource DataGridRowStyle1}" ColumnHeaderStyle="{DynamicResource DataGridColumnHeaderStyle1}" 
          CellStyle="{DynamicResource DataGridCellStyle1}" x:Name="UsersDataGrid" Style="{DynamicResource DataGridStyle1}" 
          ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True" 
        VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="#" IsReadOnly="True" CanUserResize="False" Width="70" Binding="{Binding UserId}"/>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Trigramme" IsReadOnly="True" Width="150">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Border Width="35" Height="35" CornerRadius="50" Margin="25 0 10 0" Background="{Binding Color}">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Trigramme}" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Foreground="White" Margin="0 0 0 1"/>
                        </Border>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="FirstName" Binding="{Binding FirstName}" IsReadOnly="True" Width="*"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="LastName" Binding="{Binding LastName}" IsReadOnly="True" Width="*"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="UserName" Binding="{Binding UserName}" IsReadOnly="True" Width="*"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Password" Binding="{Binding Password}" IsReadOnly="True" Width="*"/>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Operations" IsReadOnly="True" Width="auto">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Button Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGrid}, Path=DataContext.UpdateUserCommand}"
                                Margin="5 0 0 0" Style="{StaticResource datagridEditButton}" >
                            <Icon:PackIconMaterial Kind="PencilOutline" Style="{StaticResource datagridButtonIcon}"/>
                        </Button>
                        <Button Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGrid}, Path=DataContext.RemoveUserCommand}" 
                                Margin="5 0 0 0" Style="{StaticResource datagridRemoveButton}">
                            <Icon:PackIconMaterial Kind="DeleteOutline" Style="{StaticResource datagridButtonIcon}"/>
                        </Button>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>

Datagrid style :
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:Icon="http://metro.mahapps.com/winfx/xaml/iconpacks"
                    xmlns:theme="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Windows.Themes;assembly=PresentationFramework.Aero2">

    <!--// Datagrid //-->
    <Style x:Key="{ComponentResourceKey ResourceId=DataGridSelectAllButtonStyle, TypeInTargetAssembly={x:Type DataGrid}}" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                    <Grid>
                        <Rectangle x:Name="Border" Fill="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}}" SnapsToDevicePixels="True"/>
                        <Polygon x:Name="Arrow" Fill="Black" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="8,8,3,3" Opacity="0.15" Points="0,10 10,10 10,0" Stretch="Uniform" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"/>
                    </Grid>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="Border" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlDarkBrushKey}}"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="Border" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlDarkBrushKey}}"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                            <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="Arrow" Value="Collapsed"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

    <Style x:Key="DataGridStyle1" TargetType="{x:Type DataGrid}">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#222528"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
        <Setter Property="RowDetailsVisibilityMode" Value="VisibleWhenSelected"/>
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="true"/>
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.PanningMode" Value="Both"/>
        <Setter Property="Stylus.IsFlicksEnabled" Value="False"/>
        <Setter Property="AutoGenerateColumns" Value="False" />
        <Setter Property="HeadersVisibility" Value="Column" />
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0 10 0 0" />
        <Setter Property="Grid.Row" Value="5" />
        <Setter Property="SelectionMode" Value="Single" />
        <Setter Property="SelectionUnit" Value="FullRow" />
        <Setter Property="CanUserAddRows" Value="False" />
        <Setter Property="CanUserDeleteRows" Value="False" />
        <Setter Property="CanUserReorderColumns" Value="False" />
        <Setter Property="CanUserResizeRows" Value="False" />
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="13" />
        <Setter Property="GridLinesVisibility" Value="None" />
        <Setter Property="ColumnWidth" Value="*" />

        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGrid}">
                    <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                        <ScrollViewer x:Name="DG_ScrollViewer" Focusable="false">
                            <ScrollViewer.Template>
                                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ScrollViewer}">
                                    <Grid>
                                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <Button Command="{x:Static DataGrid.SelectAllCommand}" Focusable="false" Style="{DynamicResource {ComponentResourceKey ResourceId=DataGridSelectAllButtonStyle, TypeInTargetAssembly={x:Type DataGrid}}}" Visibility="{Binding HeadersVisibility, Converter={x:Static DataGrid.HeadersVisibilityConverter}, ConverterParameter={x:Static DataGridHeadersVisibility.All}, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}" Width="{Binding CellsPanelHorizontalOffset, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}"/>
                                        <DataGridColumnHeadersPresenter x:Name="PART_ColumnHeadersPresenter" Grid.Column="1" Visibility="{Binding HeadersVisibility, Converter={x:Static DataGrid.HeadersVisibilityConverter}, ConverterParameter={x:Static DataGridHeadersVisibility.Column}, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}"/>
                                        <ScrollContentPresenter x:Name="PART_ScrollContentPresenter" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" CanContentScroll="{TemplateBinding CanContentScroll}" Grid.Row="1"/>
                                        <ScrollBar x:Name="PART_VerticalScrollBar" Grid.Column="2" Maximum="{TemplateBinding ScrollableHeight}" Orientation="Vertical" Grid.Row="1" ViewportSize="{TemplateBinding ViewportHeight}" Value="{Binding VerticalOffset, Mode=OneWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Visibility="{TemplateBinding ComputedVerticalScrollBarVisibility}"/>
                                        <Grid Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2">
                                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="{Binding NonFrozenColumnsViewportHorizontalOffset, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}"/>
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                            <ScrollBar x:Name="PART_HorizontalScrollBar" Grid.Column="1" Maximum="{TemplateBinding ScrollableWidth}" Orientation="Horizontal" ViewportSize="{TemplateBinding ViewportWidth}" Value="{Binding HorizontalOffset, Mode=OneWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Visibility="{TemplateBinding ComputedHorizontalScrollBarVisibility}"/>
                                        </Grid>
                                    </Grid>
                                </ControlTemplate>
                            </ScrollViewer.Template>
                            <ItemsPresenter SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
                        </ScrollViewer>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <MultiTrigger>
                <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Condition Property="IsGrouping" Value="true"/>
                    <Condition Property="VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizingWhenGrouping" Value="false"/>
                </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="false"/>
            </MultiTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>

    <Style x:Key="DataGridRowStyle1" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0 4 0 0" />
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FFFFFF"/>
        <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="true"/>
        <Setter Property="Validation.ErrorTemplate" Value="{x:Null}"/>
        <Setter Property="ValidationErrorTemplate">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Foreground="Red" Margin="2,0,0,0" Text="!" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
                    <Border x:Name="DGR_Border" Padding="0 8" CornerRadius="5" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderThickness="0" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                        <SelectiveScrollingGrid>
                            <SelectiveScrollingGrid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            </SelectiveScrollingGrid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <SelectiveScrollingGrid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                            </SelectiveScrollingGrid.RowDefinitions>
                            <DataGridCellsPresenter Grid.Column="1" ItemsPanel="{TemplateBinding ItemsPanel}" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
                            <DataGridDetailsPresenter Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" SelectiveScrollingGrid.SelectiveScrollingOrientation="{Binding AreRowDetailsFrozen, Converter={x:Static DataGrid.RowDetailsScrollingConverter}, ConverterParameter={x:Static SelectiveScrollingOrientation.Vertical}, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}" Visibility="{TemplateBinding DetailsVisibility}"/>
                            <DataGridRowHeader Grid.RowSpan="2" SelectiveScrollingGrid.SelectiveScrollingOrientation="Vertical" Visibility="{Binding HeadersVisibility, Converter={x:Static DataGrid.HeadersVisibilityConverter}, ConverterParameter={x:Static DataGridHeadersVisibility.Row}, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}"/>
                        </SelectiveScrollingGrid>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>

        <Style.Triggers>
            <!--<Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">-->
            <!--<Setter Property="Background" Value="#623ED0"/> -->
            <!--<Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#ffffff"/>-->
            <!--</Trigger>-->
            <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="#024950"/>
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#ffffff"/>
            </Trigger>
            <MultiTrigger>
                <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="true"/>
                    <Condition Property="Selector.IsSelectionActive" Value="false"/>
                </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="#dfdfdf"/>
            </MultiTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>

    <Style x:Key="DataGridCellStyle1" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
        <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}" />
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="15 0" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
                    <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderThickness="0" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                        <ContentPresenter SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

    <Style x:Key="ColumnHeaderGripperStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Thumb}">
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="8"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
        <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="SizeWE"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Thumb}">
                    <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"/>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

    <Style x:Key="DataGridColumnHeaderStyle1" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#69717D" />
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="15 0 15 10" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
                    <Grid>
                        <theme:DataGridHeaderBorder Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" IsClickable="{TemplateBinding CanUserSort}" IsPressed="{TemplateBinding IsPressed}" IsHovered="{TemplateBinding IsMouseOver}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" SeparatorBrush="{TemplateBinding SeparatorBrush}" SortDirection="{TemplateBinding SortDirection}" SeparatorVisibility="{TemplateBinding SeparatorVisibility}">
                            <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                        </theme:DataGridHeaderBorder>
                        <Thumb x:Name="PART_LeftHeaderGripper" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Style="{StaticResource ColumnHeaderGripperStyle}"/>
                        <Thumb x:Name="PART_RightHeaderGripper" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Style="{StaticResource ColumnHeaderGripperStyle}"/>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

    <!--// Button Datagrid //-->
    <Style x:Key="datagridEditButton" TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#ffbd03" />
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#ffbd03" />
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#ffffff" />
        <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}" />
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
        <Setter Property="Template" >
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                    <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" Padding="5" BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="5">
                        <ContentPresenter VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Orange" />
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>

    <Style x:Key="datagridRemoveButton" TargetType="Button" BasedOn="{StaticResource datagridEditButton}">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#dd7973" />
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#dd7973" />
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="#F44336" />
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>

    <Style x:Key="datagridButtonIcon" TargetType="Icon:PackIconMaterial">
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="12" />
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="12" />
    </Style>

</ResourceDictionary>

Thank you in advance for reading and helping me.

I think your situation called for a ListView with "one" item template that by default is selectable. Instead you've "templated" a data grid; that is rarely "templated" as you have.

Add VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalAlignment}" to DataGridCell's ContentPresenter.

Thank you for your answers @emoacht.
I've added your code in DataGridCell template, but it doesn't change anything in GUI. Is it in my DataGridCell template ? Do I need to change anything else in the code? Padding? Margin?




Thank you for your answers @GerrySchmitz.
When I did my research at the beginning, I read that for modifications, it was better to use the datagrid. In my datagrid, I display the data from my database and add, modify and delete them. Is ListView suitable for this? Is it possible to customize the ListView GUI?

@SnoxEcko Could you show after removing padding, margin and setting vertical alignment to Stretch?

@emoacht Yes, this is the 3rd screenshot in my post

@SnoxEcko Sorry for typo. Could you show the styles after you did removing padding, margin and setting vertical alignment to Stretch?

@emoacht I added the code in an answer.

Your issue is you have too many "selectable" fields and small "hit" areas. The ListView is not better than the Grid, but if you're just interested in "selecting items", a "list" (type of) control (and an item data template) is more suitable. I know the "column - row" pattern shows up frequently, but more "advanced" UI's don't use them ... the "data grid" is not even a "native" UWP/WPF control; it's a  "toolkit" item. "Templating" items "creatively" is the current state. There are no "grids" (except for calendars) in Outlook, for example.

@GerrySchmitz I'll make a note of that. I'll try to make a listView next to it to compare. Thanks for your suggestion.

Based on your revised Styles, if you use VerticalAlignment to streach DataGridCell, use VerticalContentAlignment and refer it in ControlTemplate.
<Style x:Key="DataGridCellStyle1" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
    <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
                <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                        BorderThickness="0"
                        SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                    <ContentPresenter VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>


Following the suggestion of @emoacht, here's the code with the addition of VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalAlignment}" and the removal of padding and margin. I've also set VerticalAlignment to Stretch. The result is a little less good than what I would like to do.
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                xmlns:Icon="http://metro.mahapps.com/winfx/xaml/iconpacks"
                xmlns:theme="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Windows.Themes;assembly=PresentationFramework.Aero2">

<!--// Datagrid //-->
<Style x:Key="{ComponentResourceKey ResourceId=DataGridSelectAllButtonStyle, TypeInTargetAssembly={x:Type DataGrid}}" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <Grid>
                    <Rectangle x:Name="Border" Fill="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}}" SnapsToDevicePixels="True"/>
                    <Polygon x:Name="Arrow" Fill="Black" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="8,8,3,3" Opacity="0.15" Points="0,10 10,10 10,0" Stretch="Uniform" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"/>
                </Grid>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="Border" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlDarkBrushKey}}"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="Border" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlDarkBrushKey}}"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                        <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="Arrow" Value="Collapsed"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>

<Style x:Key="DataGridStyle1" TargetType="{x:Type DataGrid}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#222528"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
    <Setter Property="RowDetailsVisibilityMode" Value="VisibleWhenSelected"/>
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="true"/>
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.PanningMode" Value="Both"/>
    <Setter Property="Stylus.IsFlicksEnabled" Value="False"/>
    <Setter Property="AutoGenerateColumns" Value="False" />
    <Setter Property="HeadersVisibility" Value="Column" />
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0 10 0 0" />
    <Setter Property="Grid.Row" Value="5" />
    <Setter Property="SelectionMode" Value="Single" />
    <Setter Property="SelectionUnit" Value="FullRow" />
    <Setter Property="CanUserAddRows" Value="False" />
    <Setter Property="CanUserDeleteRows" Value="False" />
    <Setter Property="CanUserReorderColumns" Value="False" />
    <Setter Property="CanUserResizeRows" Value="False" />
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="13" />
    <Setter Property="GridLinesVisibility" Value="None" />
    <Setter Property="ColumnWidth" Value="*" />

    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGrid}">
                <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                    <ScrollViewer x:Name="DG_ScrollViewer" Focusable="false">
                        <ScrollViewer.Template>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ScrollViewer}">
                                <Grid>
                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <Button Command="{x:Static DataGrid.SelectAllCommand}" Focusable="false" Style="{DynamicResource {ComponentResourceKey ResourceId=DataGridSelectAllButtonStyle, TypeInTargetAssembly={x:Type DataGrid}}}" Visibility="{Binding HeadersVisibility, Converter={x:Static DataGrid.HeadersVisibilityConverter}, ConverterParameter={x:Static DataGridHeadersVisibility.All}, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}" Width="{Binding CellsPanelHorizontalOffset, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}"/>
                                    <DataGridColumnHeadersPresenter x:Name="PART_ColumnHeadersPresenter" Grid.Column="1" Visibility="{Binding HeadersVisibility, Converter={x:Static DataGrid.HeadersVisibilityConverter}, ConverterParameter={x:Static DataGridHeadersVisibility.Column}, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}"/>
                                    <ScrollContentPresenter x:Name="PART_ScrollContentPresenter" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" CanContentScroll="{TemplateBinding CanContentScroll}" Grid.Row="1"/>
                                    <ScrollBar x:Name="PART_VerticalScrollBar" Grid.Column="2" Maximum="{TemplateBinding ScrollableHeight}" Orientation="Vertical" Grid.Row="1" ViewportSize="{TemplateBinding ViewportHeight}" Value="{Binding VerticalOffset, Mode=OneWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Visibility="{TemplateBinding ComputedVerticalScrollBarVisibility}"/>
                                    <Grid Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2">
                                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="{Binding NonFrozenColumnsViewportHorizontalOffset, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}"/>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ScrollBar x:Name="PART_HorizontalScrollBar" Grid.Column="1" Maximum="{TemplateBinding ScrollableWidth}" Orientation="Horizontal" ViewportSize="{TemplateBinding ViewportWidth}" Value="{Binding HorizontalOffset, Mode=OneWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Visibility="{TemplateBinding ComputedHorizontalScrollBarVisibility}"/>
                                    </Grid>
                                </Grid>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </ScrollViewer.Template>
                        <ItemsPresenter SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
                    </ScrollViewer>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <MultiTrigger>
            <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                <Condition Property="IsGrouping" Value="true"/>
                <Condition Property="VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizingWhenGrouping" Value="false"/>
            </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="false"/>
        </MultiTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>

<Style x:Key="DataGridRowStyle1" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0 4 0 0" />
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FFFFFF"/>
    <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="true"/>
    <Setter Property="Validation.ErrorTemplate" Value="{x:Null}"/>
    <Setter Property="ValidationErrorTemplate">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <TextBlock Foreground="Red" Margin="2,0,0,0" Text="!" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
                <Border x:Name="DGR_Border" CornerRadius="5" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderThickness="0" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                    <SelectiveScrollingGrid>
                        <SelectiveScrollingGrid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        </SelectiveScrollingGrid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <SelectiveScrollingGrid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        </SelectiveScrollingGrid.RowDefinitions>
                        <DataGridCellsPresenter Grid.Column="1" ItemsPanel="{TemplateBinding ItemsPanel}" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
                        <DataGridDetailsPresenter Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" SelectiveScrollingGrid.SelectiveScrollingOrientation="{Binding AreRowDetailsFrozen, Converter={x:Static DataGrid.RowDetailsScrollingConverter}, ConverterParameter={x:Static SelectiveScrollingOrientation.Vertical}, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}" Visibility="{TemplateBinding DetailsVisibility}"/>
                        <DataGridRowHeader Grid.RowSpan="2" SelectiveScrollingGrid.SelectiveScrollingOrientation="Vertical" Visibility="{Binding HeadersVisibility, Converter={x:Static DataGrid.HeadersVisibilityConverter}, ConverterParameter={x:Static DataGridHeadersVisibility.Row}, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}"/>
                    </SelectiveScrollingGrid>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>

    <Style.Triggers>
        <!--<Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">-->
        <!--<Setter Property="Background" Value="#623ED0"/> -->
        <!--<Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#ffffff"/>-->
        <!--</Trigger>-->
        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#024950"/>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#ffffff"/>
        </Trigger>
        <MultiTrigger>
            <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="true"/>
                <Condition Property="Selector.IsSelectionActive" Value="false"/>
            </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#dfdfdf"/>
        </MultiTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>

<Style x:Key="DataGridCellStyle1" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
    <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
                <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderThickness="0" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                    <ContentPresenter SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalAlignment}"/>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>

<Style x:Key="ColumnHeaderGripperStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Thumb}">
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="8"/>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
    <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="SizeWE"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Thumb}">
                <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"/>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>

<Style x:Key="DataGridColumnHeaderStyle1" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#69717D" />
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="15 0 15 10" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
                <Grid>
                    <theme:DataGridHeaderBorder Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" IsClickable="{TemplateBinding CanUserSort}" IsPressed="{TemplateBinding IsPressed}" IsHovered="{TemplateBinding IsMouseOver}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" SeparatorBrush="{TemplateBinding SeparatorBrush}" SortDirection="{TemplateBinding SortDirection}" SeparatorVisibility="{TemplateBinding SeparatorVisibility}">
                        <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                    </theme:DataGridHeaderBorder>
                    <Thumb x:Name="PART_LeftHeaderGripper" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Style="{StaticResource ColumnHeaderGripperStyle}"/>
                    <Thumb x:Name="PART_RightHeaderGripper" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Style="{StaticResource ColumnHeaderGripperStyle}"/>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>

<!--// Button Datagrid //-->
<Style x:Key="datagridEditButton" TargetType="Button">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#ffbd03" />
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#ffbd03" />
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#ffffff" />
    <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}" />
    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
    <Setter Property="Template" >
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" Padding="5" BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="5">
                    <ContentPresenter VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Orange" />
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>

<Style x:Key="datagridRemoveButton" TargetType="Button" BasedOn="{StaticResource datagridEditButton}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#dd7973" />
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#dd7973" />
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#F44336" />
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>

<Style x:Key="datagridButtonIcon" TargetType="Icon:PackIconMaterial">
    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="12" />
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="12" />
</Style>


Thank you @emoacht !
That's much better. I've added some margin in the contentPresenter to have a bit of margin between the rows.
<Style x:Key="DataGridCellStyle1" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
<Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
<Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
<Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
<Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}"/>
<Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
            <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                BorderThickness="0"
                SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                <ContentPresenter Margin="10" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
            </Border>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>

